# Lower bound on sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics

Is there a good lower bound for the tail of sums of binomial coefficients, so a lower bound for $\sum_{i=1}^k {n \choose 2i-1}$?

Comment: Wait, why are you only summing the $\binom{n}{j}$ with $j$ odd?

Comment: Summing over odd indices is equivalent to decreasing $n$ by 1, so this isn't any more complex than the basic tail-sum.